# Replacing single line breaks with html line breaks only when allowed in context

Tags: php, line-breaks, nl2br

I'm looking to replace single line breaks (doubles will already be gone) into `<br>` tags, but *only* when they are allowed in the context.

For example, consider the below:

```
<ul>
  <li>cat</li>
  <li>dog</li>
  <li>fish</li>
  <li>horse</li>
</ul>
```

`<br>` tags are *not* allowed in many of the areas in the above code, but running the usual simple replacement/addition code such as using `nl2br()` or running a `str_replace()` will obviously not follow these context rules.

For the above you would need to follow these rules:

- Line breaks **BEFORE** the *starting* list tag *should* be converted
- Line breaks **AFTER** the *starting* list tag *shouldn't* be converted
- Line breaks **BEFORE** the *starting* list item tag *shouldn't* be converted
- Line breaks **AFTER** the *starting* list item tag *should* be converted
- Line breaks **BEFORE** the *closing* list item tag *should* be converted
- Line breaks **AFTER** the *closing* list item tag *shouldn't* be converted
- Line breaks **BEFORE** the *closing* list tag *shouldn't* be converted
- Line breaks **AFTER** the *closing* list tag *should* be converted

Is there are current functions / libraries that can do this functionality already? Surely this is a common problem, so I imagine there must be something.

Comment: With the risk of sounding rude, I think `nl2br` is not meant to be used on HTML strings. You should either go with HTML (where new line characters are irrelevant) or plain old strings (where you are free to replace new lines with `<br />`).
Are you by any chance running this on some user-provided input, which may or may not contain HTML?

Comment: @Grampa It's actually going to be run on html, which has been parsed from `bbcode` from user input. I am using `htmlpurifier` to auto do the paragraphs but it doesn't handle single line breaks unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

This would be complex to do in PHP. nl2br isn't suitable to preserve HTML in the text you want to process, so you would have to use a DOM parser to do this.

Or you could write your own function that loops through the entire text. Every time it encounters an opening `<` it should keep a flag, which is reset after a `>`. When it encounters a newline characters, it can check the flag to see if the character should be preserved or replaced by `<br>`. This way you can build the result string character by character. Note that invalid markup may easily break such a function.

But I think a simpler, and much better solution is to simply add a small piece of CSS:

```
white-space: pre-line;
```

Apply this to the parent of the list (and implicitly to the list and its items too). That will cause the text to behave as normal, with the exception that the text is broken too on newline characters in the text.

Comment: Well I'm more concerned with the overall scheme of things than just "fixing" list tags and as well as preserving semantically correct code. I like the idea of your function, but as you say it could be broken with invalid markup - though I suppose the code could be ran through something like `tidy` beforehand?

Comment: Yes of course. But also, a little broken isn't too bad. But for instance a falsely unescaped `<` in the text could put a simple parser in 'tag' mode, after which it won't change `\n` in `<br>` anymore until a `>` is encountered. Likewise, an unescaped `>` inside an attribute value in a tag will cause a simple parser to think the tag has ended, and it will start replacing, while it shouldn't. Still, depending on where your input comes from, this might be acceptable for you (you may assume that the bbcode processor returns valid HTML). But have you considered the CSS solution?

Comment: After what you said I reconfirmed and the bbcode parser does state it returns valid html even from badly mangled bbcode; so I don't think that should be an issue. Prefer to steer clear of that css fix as I do want to try and output correct code and not be stuck with elements in places that they shouldn't be.